# Scala console application never exits when awaiting Futures

Tags: scala, playframework, future, threadpoolexecutor, executioncontext

Whenever I run a scala process that uses the result of a `Future` (either through `Await`, `map`, `onComplete`, etc.), it never exits, forcing us to kill the process manually.  This occurs whether I use `extends App` or just a standard `def main(args: Array[String])` method.

It seems to me that it is related to the `ThreadPoolExecutor` that scala will spin up to execute the `Future` is hanging around at the end of the function, but I can't seem to get a handle to it to close it out.

For example, the following code will fail to exit:

```
object ExecuteApi extends App with StrictLogging{

  lazy val config = StratumConfiguration.setupConfiguration()
  lazy val apiEndpoint = config.getProperty("APIEndpoint").split("/").head
  lazy val packetApiPath = "packets/getpackets"

  val resourceNames = sys.env.getOrElse("ResourceNames", "").stripMargin.split("[\n\\s]+").map(_.trim).filterNot(_.isEmpty)
  val searchBody =
  s"""{
    |  "resourceNames": [
    |    "${(resourceNames).mkString("\",\"")}"
    |  ]
    |}""".stripMargin
    logger.info(searchBody)
    val responseFuture = AmazonAsyncApiGatewayHelper.executeHttpRequest(apiEndpoint, searchBody, Some(packetApiPath), Some("api"))
    val response = Await.result(responseFuture, Duration(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    val layerDefinitions = Json.parse(response)
    println(Json.prettyPrint(layerDefinitions))
}
```

While this code exits just fine (the only change is the Async version that returns a future, which is then Awaited) :

```
object ExecuteAPI extends App with StrictLogging{

  lazy val config = Configuration.setupConfiguration()
  lazy val apiEndpoint = config.getProperty("APIEndpoint").split("/").head
  lazy val packetApiPath = "packets/getpackets"

  val resourceNames = sys.env.getOrElse("ResourceNames", "").stripMargin.split("\n").map(_.trim).filterNot(_.isEmpty)

  val searchBody =
  s"""{
    |  "resourceNames": [
    |    "${(resourceNames).mkString("\",\"")}"
    |  ]
    |}""".stripMargin
    logger.info(searchBody)
    val layersResponse = AmazonapiGatewayHelper.executeHttpRequest(apiEndpoint, searchBody, Some(packetApiPath), Some("api"))
    val layerDefinitions = Json.parse(layersResponse)
    println(Json.prettyPrint(layerDefinitions))
}
```

The code in `AmazonAsyncApiGatewayHelper` eventually creates the Future by executing the Play library HTTP client.  However, we have seen this when executing Futures in other ways as well:

```
val request = wsClient.url(fullUrl)
    .withRequestTimeout(readTimeout)
val requestWithHeaders = headers.foldLeft(request) { (r, h) =>
  r.withHeaders(h)
}
val playResponseFuture = requestWithHeaders.post(requestBody)
```

Comment: I see the result in both cases, but in the first case, the process never exits after the result is returned.

Comment: Sorry, where is that Helper class? Generally, if the thread pool creates daemon threads, the app will exit quietly.

Comment: I'll update the question with details on this case, but it happens for anything we run that accesses a Future result

Comment: @som-snytt, thanks for the comment, it eventually led us to find the issue was one of the thread pools created by the Play lib not exiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up finding the issue. The Play wsClient requires an actor system (starting in Play 2.5).  We needed to manually terminate this actor system before we exited our main class. The code that exits looks like:

```
object ExecuteAPI extends App with StrictLogging{
 try {
  lazy val config = Configuration.setupConfiguration()
  lazy val apiEndpoint = config.getProperty("APIEndpoint").split("/").head
  lazy val packetApiPath = "packets/getpackets"

  val resourceNames = sys.env.getOrElse("ResourceNames", "").stripMargin.split("\n").map(_.trim).filterNot(_.isEmpty)

  val searchBody =
  s"""{
    |  "resourceNames": [
    |    "${(resourceNames).mkString("\",\"")}"
    |  ]
    |}""".stripMargin
    logger.info(searchBody)
    val responseFuture = AmazonAsyncApiGatewayHelper.executeHttpRequest(apiEndpoint, searchBody, Some(packetApiPath), Some("api"))
    val response = Await.result(responseFuture, Duration(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    val layerDefinitions = Json.parse(response)
    println(Json.prettyPrint(layerDefinitions))
 } finally {
    AmazonAsyncApiGatewayHelper.client.actorSystem.terminate()
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can map over future value and adding `Thread.sleep()` at the end.

```
val result = layersResponse  map { futureValue =>
 Json.parse(layerResponse)
}

Thread.sleep(10000)
println(Json.prettyPrint(result))
```

Comment: You would need to make result a var and set it in the Future.  Either way, this has the same issue.  I updated the question.